# using v-for with multiple keys

Tags: vue.js

So I am going to be honest I am NOT sure if using multiple keys is the right solution but in my head it is what makes sense. Here is the task at hand.

I have 3 objects I am showing in a v-for statement:

[image]

The bottom item (CHILD OF 1) should be located under PARENT 1. Now, in my code, I have the following

`<div class="text-white" v-for="comment in comments" :key="comment.id">`

Now, there is another field in the object called `comment.parent_id` That relates back to the original `comment.id`

How would I go about properly sorting this so that I can format the comments accordingly. (side note not that it matters, but, ill be indenting the child comment which is why this is important).

Thanks!

Comment: You should probably look into `recursive components` and see how to implement those, basically Reddit-style. It should be pretty much nesting each comment inside of it's parent inside of it's parent etc...

Comment: @kissu I am going to ask you one last time PLEASE STOP COMMENTING ON MY POSTS. You are not helping me by offering solutions and your downvoting of my questions is truly becoming harassing. Please stop you are quite abusive and NOT helpful!

Comment: 1. I'm offering you a quite nice solution, just Google for it. Regarding the effort put upfront, it's quite good already IMO. 2. I didn't down-voted your question as you can see. 3. Not sure how I am abusive. 4. Sorry if I don't remember your name specifically, you're a guy like anybody else to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution for only one depth**

I would organize the data differently and use a different approach.
The data would be more coherent if you have an object list with your parent comments and your parent object has a child comment object list.

Example:

```js
   comments = [{
               id: 1,
               username: "John SMITH",
               timestamp: "9999-12-31 23:59:59.999999",
               text: "This is a parent comment",
               commentChild: [{
                               id: 2,
                               username: "Angela SMITH",
                               timestamp: "9999-12-31 23:59:59.999999",
                               text: "This is a Child comment",
                              },]
               },]
```

With this it is easy to make a first for loop to browse your parents and within it, a for loop to browse the children, if there are any.

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <template v-for="comment in comments" :key="comment.id">
      <div>Your parent comment data</div>
      <template v-for="commentChild in comment.commentChild" :key="commentChild.id">
        <div>Your child comment data</div>
      </template>
    </template>
  </div>
</template>
```

**Solution for infinite depth**

To handle an unknown depth, you must have a recursive component and a parent component that will initiate the first call.

This is what it can do:

*Comment Interface*

```js
interface Comment {
  id: number;
  comments?: Comment[];
// And all data you want
}
```

*Component Parent (initial call)*:

```js
<template>
//Only here for call the recursive component
// Take your list of comments
  <MyCommentsRecursiveComponent :comments="comments"></Test>
</template>
```

*MyCommentsRecursiveComponent:*

```js
<script setup lang="ts">

defineProps<{ comments: Comment[] }>();

</script>

<template>
  <div>
    <template v-for="(actualComment, index) in comments">
      <p>{{ actualComment.id }}</p>
      <div>
        // Component call himself / Recursive
        <MyCommentsRecursiveComponent
          v-if="actualComment.comments"
          :comments="actualComment.comments"
        ></MyCommentsRecursiveComponent>
      </div>
    </template>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: This solution is great but don't go for more than a depth of 2.

Comment: Editing my answer with multiple depth solution

Comment: @fchancel The issue I am dealing with is this is a Laravel package. So my available data is Parent ID, Child ID and Text (obviously more but that would be what applies to this question). So I need a way to maybe sort or edit the data. Ive thought about using a computed or another way to combine the parent and child id so it would be 1.0 (parent) 1.1, 1.2 (children)